# How to permanently get rid of the underline of hyperlinks in Microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, underlining

I modified the style, but when I click on the hyperlink it again gets underlined.

What should I do to permanently get rid of the underline in hyperlinks in a MS Word document?

Comment: Not a duplicate at all, they want to disable underlining of hyperlinks globally for a single document during its creation, I don't think it can be done.

Comment: Did you also modify the style FollowedHyperlink to remove underlining from that?

Comment: @Tanya Yes and that solve the problem.